# How do I set up several custom UIViewControllers under one central view controller programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Being new to Xcode and Objective-C I find it hard to get my head around the Interface builder and Objective-C when doing things that are following the basic pattern. I have created a subclass of UIViewController that I want to instantiate several times to make a grid with each row being controlled by an instance of this class. So there will be one root view controller (with navigation etc) that should include/genereate all the instances of the custom sub-viewcontroller.

Now what would be the best way to do this? All examples I can find are about navigation, where one view should replace another, but I want to have all the viewcontrollers visible on the same "page". Do I need to create a nib file for the custom controller at all? I have also been thinking about using the UITableView somehow but inserting my custom viewcontroller in every row.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's documentation recommends using one view controller per screen.  It is possible to  decompose your interface and use multiple view controllers on one screen if you have a good reason to do it, but Apple hasn't really designed their frameworks to support this, so you'll run into pitfalls if you don't know what you're doing.

In this case, I question whether each row of your grid really needs its own view controller.  I find it hard to imagine a case where this would be the best choice, although it's hard to say for sure without knowing more about your app.  Some things to consider:

- What is your custom controller doing?  Is it mostly changing the visual appearance of its corresponding grid row?  If so, perhaps it would be more appropriate to subclass the UIView itself.
- If this object is really behaving as a controller and not a view, consider implementing it as a subclass of NSObject rather than subclassing UIViewController.  The UIViewController for your screen can capture events and delegate them to the appropriate custom controller object, or your custom views can capture their own events and notify their associated controllers of those events directly using a delegate pattern.
- If you're sure you have a valid reason to implement these objects as UIViewController subclasses, check out my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631963/best-way-to-combine-existing-views-controllers/3633067#3633067) question.